# Add img attributes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, setattribute, createelement

I know that this question has been asked several times, but I have problems when I try to `appendChild` the `img` to a `div`.
Here is the code:

```js
var picture = document.createElement("img");
 picture.id= "xmark";
picture.src= "x.png";
picture.setAttribute("position","absolute");       
picture.setAttribute("bottom", 100 + 'px'); 
picture.setAttribute("left",500 + 'px');
//I also tried
picture.style.bottom= 100 + 'px'; 
picture.style.left = 100 + 'px';  
// I even tried this, but returns "cannot read property style of null" error
document.getElementById("xmark").style.bottom=100+"px";

document.getElementById("divmax").appendChild(picture);
```

```html
<div id="divmax"></div>
```

Yes, the jpg files are saved correctly. I checked.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Of course trying to find the picture in the document will fail - you only add it AFTER the lookup. If you swap the last two JS lines, it works.

Comment: the problem is that nothing happens. the style is not changed by my attribution

Comment: picture.style.position like this add others

Answer (score 0):

This is working, just change your `position` property so it's like the other way you tried:

```js
var picture = document.createElement("img");
picture.id= "xmark";
picture.src= "https://placehold.it/250x250";
picture.style.position = 'absolute';
picture.style.bottom = 100 + 'px'; 
picture.style.left = 100 + 'px';  

document.getElementById("divmax").appendChild(picture);
```

```html
<div id="divmax"></div>
```